# Edubuntu with KDE desktop environment

Tags: kde, edubuntu

Can somebody help me. Is there an Edubuntu distribution with KDE? If yes, where can I download it? Thank you

Comment: Edubuntu is based on the Gnome Desktop. So it isn't possible at the moment to have an "out-of-the-box" Edubuntu experience with KDE as a desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Edubuntu can be grabbed either via

- their website https://www.edubuntu.org/
- or just download directly from https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/

Edubuntu uses the default GNOME Desktop of Ubuntu Desktop, as there are security benefits of that relationship.  The team have covered alternate desktops in [*some of*] their blogs/communications.

[Edubuntu 23.04 release statement is found on the Ubuntu Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/edubuntu-23-04-released/35281)

Comment: I'd like to provide a link to the *flavor* discussions, alas I can't recall where/when it was, and don't have time to look (we're awfully close to 22.04.3 release etc)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Kubuntu https://kubuntu.org/ if you want Ubuntu with KDE

Comment: I think Edubuntu is mostly about ease of installing a particular set of packages (via Edubuntu Installer) and hiding select menu items (via Edubuntu Menu Administrator). So yes, you can install Kubuntu, and then manually install all the software that you want (without the assistance of the Edubuntu tools).